# shell: save and restore mtime based on sha1 hash

Tags: python, perl, shell, openbsd, filemtime

I have a set of several thousand files that are automatically re-generated every 24-hours (e.g. [ports-readmes](https://github.com/cnst/ports-readmes/) on OpenBSD).

Most of the time, the content of these files doesn't change, but since they are re-created, the `mtime` does change.

Without modifying the original app which re-generates the files in place, how would I cache the mtime based on the filename/sha1 pairs, and restore after the regeneration if sha1 stays the same?  Prefer `python`, but any UNIX solution is welcome.

(I require this for a sitemap, since the sitemap spec only has `lastmod` for versioning.)

Comment: SO is not a coding service.

Comment: This is an entirely general problem, and could most certainly be solved through a rather small script.

Comment: @cnst - Agreed. So try to write that small script. If you have trouble, come back with a specific question. You'll get plenty of answers then.

Comment: SO is not a coding service, even for small scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear precisely what help you require. Here are some places to start:

- You can use `os.walk`, `os.listdir` or `glob.glob` to generate a list of files.
- You can use `os.stat` to determine the last modified time.
- You can use `hashlib.md5(open(fname).read()).hexdigest()` to get the md5.
- You can use `os.utime` to set the modified time of a file.
- You can use `json.dump` and `json.load` to persist the mtimes from one run to the next (there are other alternatives)